# Getting an attribute from xml based associative array

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml parser that returns an associative array. Here's the structure:

```
<addresses id="123">
  <anonymous-address> <test>data 1 </test>
  </anonymous-address>
</addresses>

print_r($this->params) will return 
Array
(
    [addresses] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [anonymous-address] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (                                
                            [test] => Array
                                (
                                    [VALUE] => data 1
                                )))))
```

This array then gets passed through list() as:

```
list($root, $data) = $parsedXML;
```

Then I attempt to get an id attribute from root and read to do it this way:

```
$id = $data[$root]['id'];
```

Edit: This works for all but one $root value which it 400's for. This case of the switch ($root) has the same code as the others, so I have no idea why it errs only there.

var_dump($root, $data) outputs

```
string (9)  "addresses"
array(1)  {
    ["addresses"]=>
    array(2)  {
        ["id"]=>
        string(3)  "123"
        ["anonymous-address"]=>
        array(1)  {
            ["VALUE"]=>
            string(7)  "data 1 "
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does var_dump($root); var_dump($data) print?

Comment: you still haven't published the var_dumps. Believe me, you'll find the problem when you'll look at the output

Comment: I've edited my question to more truly reflect the structure of the xml my problem is with, and added the var_dumps.

Comment: but this is a var_dump for the one that works, isn't it? Where's the one that doesn't work?

Comment: This var_dump occurs for every value of $root my server recieves, but for some reason it 400 send errors on one particular value of $root.

Comment: it is relatively difficult to GUESS what you see if you don't let us know. So please try to concentrate on the data that produces the error. You've posted lots of info above, but it turnes out that there's no problem with all this, right? So please be so kind and post ONLY about that particular root that causes the problem, and post as much as you can (but only about that).

Comment: For example, the values <rootone>, <roottwo>, <rootthree>, and <rootfail> all take the place of the <address> tag in different server to server curls. All of those work as expected except for <rootfail> for some reason.

Comment: I assure you that the results I am posting are being caused by the code that is producing the errors. The structure stays exactly the same and at this point all I'm doing in the switch is printing out the incoming and outgoing xml. My problem is that one input, which seems to be exactly the same as the others in structure, is throwing server errors.

Comment: what happens when you change the order in the input? Let's say you move <rootfail> to be the 1st or the 2nd one?

Comment: I'm sorry for having ended up wasting your time, but I discovered the error. I hadn't realized that <rootfail> wasn't actually calling a case in my switch. My only excuse for something so simple is that the code I'm working with is sample code I recieved and I'm in the process of familiarizing myself with it as I tweak it to my needs. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You really wasted my time, so at least you can accept the answer. Next time you should listen more carefully, and you'll find it earlier. (Had you post the dumps...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = list($root, $data);
```

now $a will be:

```
array(0 => $root, 1 => $data);
```

so you can get them like this:

```
$a[0], $a[1]
```

so probably

```
$id = $a[1][$a[0]]['id'];
```

Comment: Sorry, meant to edit my question instead of comment. Accidentally hit the enter button. Please refer to my edit above.